# How to get number of frames?

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used a Intel® RealSense™ Depth Camera D435 to record several videos. I am very new to ROSBAG.

I am using [rs-convert](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/tree/master/tools/convert) to extract PNG frames from a .bag file. However, I noticed that frames have been dropped, and I am trying to identify whether the frames were dropped during recording or during extraction. To do this, I need to check the number of frames in the original .bag file.

**How can I use the rosbag command line tools to find the number of frames in a .bag file?**

(I have installed the melodic rosdistro on Ubuntu 18.04.)

EDIT:
After using the `rs-convert` tool to extract PNG files, I was able to get 20879 PNG frames.

**Is the "duration" the true length of the video?**  Since I know the D435 camera records at 30fps, I could do 20879 frames/ 699s = 29.87fps --> close enough to 30fps --> conclusion: no frames were dropped.

Below is the output when I run `rosbag info <BAG_FILE>`. Any insight on the output of this would be helpful, as I am *very new* to all this.

```
path:         <BAG_FILENAME>.bag
version:      2.0
duration:     11:39s (699s)
start:        Dec 31 1969 19:00:00.00 (0.00)
end:          Dec 31 1969 19:11:39.81 (699.81)
size:         35.9 GB
messages:     125361
compression:  lz4 [20883/20883 chunks; 66.67%]
uncompressed: 53.8 GB @ 78.7 MB/s
compressed:   35.9 GB @ 52.5 MB/s (66.67%)
types:        diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue  [cf57fdc6617a881a88c16e768132149c]
              geometry_msgs/Transform   [ac9eff44abf714214112b05d54a3cf9b]
              realsense_msgs/StreamInfo [311d7e24eac31bb87271d041bf70ff7d]
              sensor_msgs/CameraInfo    [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
              sensor_msgs/Image         [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
              std_msgs/Float32          [73fcbf46b49191e672908e50842a83d4]
              std_msgs/String           [992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1]
              std_msgs/UInt32           [304a39449588c7f8ce2df6e8001c5fce]
topics:       /device_0/info                                                         9 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_0/info                                                1 msg     : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth Units/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Depth Units/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter Enabled/description                  1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Emitter Enabled/value                        1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto Exposure/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Enable Auto Exposure/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error Polling Enabled/description            1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Error Polling Enabled/value                  1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/description                         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Exposure/value                               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames Queue Size/description                1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Frames Queue Size/value                      1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/description                             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Gain/value                                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter Cam Sync Mode/description              1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Inter Cam Sync Mode/value                    1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser Power/description                      1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Laser Power/value                            1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output Trigger Enabled/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Output Trigger Enabled/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo Baseline/description                  1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Stereo Baseline/value                        1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual Preset/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_0/option/Visual Preset/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data                              20882 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image        
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/metadata                         104410 msgs    : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info                                        1 msg     : realsense_msgs/StreamInfo
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/info/camera_info                            1 msg     : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo   
              /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/tf/0                                        1 msg     : geometry_msgs/Transform  
              /device_0/sensor_1/info                                                1 msg     : diagnostic_msgs/KeyValue 
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto Exposure Priority/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Auto Exposure Priority/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight Compensation/description           1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Backlight Compensation/value                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/description                       1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Brightness/value                             1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/description                         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Contrast/value                               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto Exposure/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto Exposure/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto White Balance/description        1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Enable Auto White Balance/value              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/description                         1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Exposure/value                               1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames Queue Size/description                1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Frames Queue Size/value                      1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/description                             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gain/value                                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/description                            1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Gamma/value                                  1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/description                              1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Hue/value                                    1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power Line Frequency/description             1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Power Line Frequency/value                   1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/description                       1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Saturation/value                             1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/description                        1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/Sharpness/value                              1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White Balance/description                    1 msg     : std_msgs/String          
              /device_0/sensor_1/option/White Balance/value                          1 msg     : std_msgs/Float32         
              /file_version                                                          1 msg     : std_msgs/UInt32
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332719/how-to-get-number-of-frames?/) by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-09-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-09-11**:
Does `rosbag info <YOUR_BAG_FILE>` help? You will see the number of messages in each topic. I'm not familiar with `rs-convert`, but if this is only converting each message of a single topic, this should be sufficient.

**Comment by [BV_Pradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/44054/bv_pradeep/) on 2019-09-11**:
@Abraham, you can use **rostopic hz <image_topic>** to find the rate at which it is being published. This applies while both recording and playing back a rosback. Usually rate of publishing and rate of recording are same in ROS

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on 2019-09-11**:
@mgruhler, I have added the output of `rosbag info <BAG_FILE>` in my question. I am not sure if this helps me.

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on 2019-09-11**:
@BV_Pradeep, I still do not completely understand how ROSBAG works, and I am not able to run `rostopic hz <image_topic>` as I cannot playback the BAG file with `rosbag play`, I am getting errors about localhost and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find the answer you're looking for in the output of `rosbag info` as recommended by @mgruhler :

```
          /device_0/sensor_1/Color_0/image/data                              20882 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
```

This tells you the bag contains 20882 `sensor_msgs/Image` messages. So based on your update, you dropped 3 frames.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on 2019-09-12**:
This worked! Thank you very much!

This is a good solution since I do not have to try to playback the BAG file, and can simply use `rosbag info`.

**Comment by [Abraham](https://answers.ros.org/users/45546/abraham/) on 2019-09-12**:
@PeteBlackerThe3rd I have a follow up question, and I have posted that here: https://answers.ros.org/question/332910/frames-dropped-during-video-recording/